# How to disable animation in list when observed object changes in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui

How do I disable animation when view model data changes?

I have the following code:

```
struct FormView: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewModel: FormViewModel

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(viewModel.options) { option in
                Text(option.displayValue)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Every time view model changes `List` gets updated with animation.
How can I disable it?
I tried adding `.animation(nil)` but it does not help

Answer (score 11):

The solution I found is to add a unique identifier that changes every time, so it will rebuild the list every time without animation. Verified on iOS 13.4.

```
var body: some View {
    List {
        ForEach(viewModel.options) { option in
            Text(option.displayValue)
        }
    }
    .id(UUID()) // no animation
}
```

Comment: Actually, `.animation(nil)` worked for me. There is a weird bug that happens like throwing exception.

Comment: @StephenLee's answer is the better one. with `.id(UUID())` you prevent SwiftUI from calculating the delta of the views resulting in redrawing everything when something has changed.

Answer (score 5):

I think the best solution is to set the UUID() as the animation value input:

```
        .animation(nil, value: UUID())
```

Answer (score 2):

The workaround till Apple give us a change to do it on List is call List.id(_:)
It change the internal state of List and force the List to recreate immediatly, without any animation. For details see [List reload animation glitches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59602045/list-reload-animation-glitches/60022550#60022550)

The same could be done on any View (func id() is part of View protocol), but you have to know that all state variables will have initial "default" state, so use it carefully. It is the same like "recreate" the View.

To be able to understand how it works, see https://swiftui-lab.com/swiftui-id/

Comment: such solution can be cause of unexpected UI behavior like refreshing all of elements instead of changed. And can be cause of UI freezes

Answer (score 0):

```
@available(macOS 10.15, *)
public extension View {
    func animationDisable() -> some View {
        self.animation(nil, value: UUID())
    }
}
```