# SwiftUI Filtering a Core Data/NSManagedObject List by Search Bar

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I have an app which uses Core Data with a FetchRequest that populates a list. I'd like to be able to allow users to search/filter the list by typing into a search bar. I've tried a few approaches, but can't seem to get it to work.

The NSManagedObject

```
public class Item: NSManagedObject, Identifiable {
    @NSManaged public var createdAt: Date?
    @NSManaged public var title: String?
    @NSManaged public var details: String?
    @NSManaged public var tag: String?
}
```

Here's my FetchRequest & state for search

```
@FetchRequest(fetchRequest: Item.getAllData()) var items: FetchedResults<Item>
@State private var searchTerm: String = ""
```

Here's where I'm attempting to allow the list to filter

```
VStack {
   SearchBar(text: $searchTerm)
   List {
      ForEach(self.items.filter({
        self.searchTerm.isEmpty ? true :
        $0.localCaseInsensitiveContains(self.searchTerm)
        }), id: \.self){ item in
        ItemView(title: item.title ?? "Title", details: item.details ?? "Details", tag: item.tag ?? "Tag")
        }
    }
}
```

With the code the way it is now, I get the following error

> Value of type 'Item' has no member 'localizedCaseInsensitiveContains'

Comment: `Item` isn’t a `String` `Item` contains strings so you’d need to filter on one or more of those.

Comment: Thanks @Magnas - I think I'm starting to understand. Since `Item` isn't a string but is made up of those four, I can't filter off it, but I can search/filter by one of the strings? How would I go about that? For example, if I wanted the list to show only those items with the tag a user is searching

Comment: Try `$0.tag.localCase...`

Comment: This did it! Thank you! I had to use `$0.tag!.local...`

Comment: any search logic, or related task should be done in your model! see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59602045/list-reload-animation-glitches/60022550#60022550 even though the answer is to different aspect ...check how search (filter) is done in the model