# Cannot prevent animation when changing TabView data (SwiftUI)

Tags: animation, swiftui, identity

My `TabView` is being populated by an array of `Identifiable` items. If the array size grows or shrinks in a way that keeps the currently visible item on screen, the view gives me an awkward flashing animation. It looks like it's transitioning from one view to another, even though the view, id, and presentation are identical

Does anyone know a way to stop the animation?

I've tried various combinations of:

1. Explicitly setting `.id()` on the `TabView`, `ForEach`, and content view
2. Setting `.transition(.identity)`
3. Setting `.animation(nil)`

but all to no avail

```
struct Item: Identifiable, Equatable {
    let id: Int
    let color: Color
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @Namespace var animation
    @State var items: [Item] = []

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TabView {
                ForEach(items, id:\.id) { item in
                    item.color
                }
            }
            .background(Color.red)
            .tabViewStyle(.page)
            .frame(width: 300, height: 300)

            HStack {
                Button("State 1") {
                    self.items = [
                        .init(id: 0, color: .green),
                        .init(id: 1, color: .blue)
                    ]
                }

                Button("State 2") {
                    self.items = [
                        .init(id: 0, color: .green),
                            .init(id: 1, color: .blue),
                            .init(id: 2, color: .purple)
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

[image: A screen recording of the simulator demonstrating the code. As the user transitions between states, the change in TabView content is animated, even thought it would be ideal for it not to be]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I'm happy to tell you I was able to solve your flashing issue with some tricks. First of all I've used a ZStack to embed the TabView and placing on top of it an item of last color you're rendering in the TabView with an opacity that can be 0 or 1 based on whether the the state is changing or not.
I'm keeping track of the last color using TabView's selection property.
Here's the code:

```
@Namespace var animation
@State private var currentItem: Color = .green
@State private var isAboutToChange = false
@State var items: [Item] = []

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        ZStack {
            TabView(selection: $currentItem) {
                ForEach(items, id:\.id) { item in
                    item.color
                        .tag(item.color)
                }
            }
            .background(Color.red)
            .tabViewStyle(.page)
            
            currentItem
                .opacity(isAboutToChange ? 1 : 0)
                .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
                    RenderColorsTabView()
                }
        }
        .frame(width: 300, height: 300)

        HStack {
            Button("State 1") {
                isAboutToChange = true
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.01) {
                    self.items = [
                        .init(id: 0, color: .green),
                        .init(id: 1, color: .blue)
                    ]
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.3) {
                    isAboutToChange = false
                }
            }

            Button("State 2") {
                isAboutToChange = true
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.01) {
                    self.items = [
                        .init(id: 0, color: .green),
                        .init(id: 1, color: .blue),
                        .init(id: 2, color: .purple)
                    ]
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.3) {
                    isAboutToChange = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
    .padding()
}


@ViewBuilder
func RenderColorsTabView() -> some View{
    TabView(selection: $currentItem) {
        ForEach(items, id:\.id) { item in
            item.color
                .tag(item.color)
        }
    }
    .tabViewStyle(.page)
}
```

As you can see I needed a boolean flag in order to notice when the change was about to happen so I could switch the opacity of the dummy color on 1 for a fraction of a second so the flashing is hidden. Another trick was to reuse the TabView to make the dummy item view look real by displaying the dots on its bottom.
Here's the result:
[image: TabView no flashing colors]

I hope to have helped you with this! Let me know if you have any doubt.

Comment: Thanks so much for figuring that out - it seems like the temporary loading item is a great way to go about it. I've also seen another solution (which I'll post as a separate comment), which is a super quick fix for simple scenarios, but for my actual problem (which involves async loading), this solution works great

Comment: Thanks to you too for sharing your knowledge here! :)

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution based on [How to disable animation in list when observed object changes in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59013217/how-to-disable-animation-in-list-when-observed-object-changes-in-swiftui/61055703#61055703)

```
var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TabView {
                ForEach(items, id:\.id) { item in
                    item.color
                }
            }
            .background(Color.red)
            .tabViewStyle(.page)
            .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
            .id(UUID())

            HStack {
                Button("State 1") {
                    self.items = [
                        .init(id: 0, color: .green),
                        .init(id: 1, color: .blue)
                    ]
                }

                Button("State 2") {
                    self.items = [
                        .init(id: 0, color: .green),
                        .init(id: 1, color: .blue),
                        .init(id: 2, color: .purple)
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
```

By setting `.id(UUID())` on the `TabView` it will always be redrawn (as opposed to its contents being redrawn), so the animation effectively goes away.

While this works for this specific example, if you have complex views on display, you may get undesirable behaviour as a result of how frequently your cells are reused